# What is (ViewController *)self.presentingViewController; in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, translate

I know this is a very stupid question but I have really no where to ask. I need to translate this line of code:

```
(ViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
```

from Objective-C to swift.

Comment: `self.presentingViewController as ViewController`

Comment: Also consider conditional casting (`as?` instead of `as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
(ViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
```

Use:

```
self.presentingViewController as ViewController
```